# META tags in Next.js React App are not readable by BrowseSEO

Tags: reactjs, seo, next.js

I got a site that built with Next.js framework. As to optimise the SEO, I added Unique `<Meta/>` tags in `<Head/>` component from `Next/Head` on each pages (index.tsx, titles/[title].tsx). However, when testing with crawling site like BrowseSEO, the Meta tags specified on each pages was not readable. Title also been displayed wrong.

Here is link to the site page in browseSEO: [Eating Animal Page](https://www.browseo.net/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.iwonder.com%2Ftitles%2FEating-Animals-4900690307d96c80354498271b604934)

Here is the snippet from `pages/titles/[title].tsx` file

```
const Title: NextPage<{ content: Content; }> = ({
  content,
}) => {
  const {title, titlePath, desc} = content
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <link rel="canonical" href={`https://www.iwonder.com${titlePath}`} />
        <title>{`Watch ${title} Streaming Online | iwonder`}</title>
        <meta key="description" name="description" content={desc} />
      </Head>
      ...
    </>
  )
}


export const getServerSideProps = async ({ req }: GetServerSidePropsContext) => {
  const { url = '' } = req
  const thePath = uri.parse(url).pathname
  const id = thePath.substring(thePath.lastIndexOf('/')
  const { content } = await getSingleTitle(id)  //fetch for content data
  return { props: { content } }
}

export default Title
```

It would be if anyone could help to highlight what is wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Did you add a <title/> tag in the <Head /> tag inside `_document.tsx`? If yes, remove it since it will lead to unexpected behavior. ([Custom Document Caveats](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document#caveats)) If you want a default title for all pages, do it in `_app.tsx`.

Comment: @Hangindev Nope, as I got it in `_app.tsx` already

Answer (score 1):

These meta tags are present on a page in DevTools but not present in the page source. So these particular meta tags are added on a client-side. You don't see them in browseSEO because it seems it's not executing JS when analyzing pages.

I assume that `page` and `desc` variables depend on the page parameter `[title]` parsed by Next.js router. `next/router` is a client-side router, so the code dependent on it can be executed only on a client-side. That is why these meta tags are added on a client side.

If you need dynamic meta tags to be present at page source at first response you'd have to pre-render it. You can use [getStaticProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation) to render at build time or [getServerSideProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering) to render at request time.

Comment: Hi Nikolai, actually I'm using  `getServerSideProps` to fetch the content data and passed it as prop to be used for META tags. I believe this should help it pre-render. I updated the snippet to include `getServerSideProps` bit.

Comment: @MohammadHarith, make sure you use the latest Next.js version and deploy the correct build. Fetching title in `getServerSideProps`  and using in `next/head` results in `title` and `meta` tags present in server response. I tested it with Next.js 9.4.4.